# Java @GeneratedValue + SQL server NEWID + Hibernate

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, id

Possuo uma tabela que possui ID definido como `CREATE DEFAULT ID_Tabelas AS NEWID()`, ou seja, mesmo que eu utilize um insert sem a chave, ela será gerada automaticamente. Como é possível fazer com o hibernate reconheça que o próprio banco irá gerar a chave da tabela?

Se eu utilizo os annotations `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)` ou `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)`, eu obtenho o seguinte erro:

```
SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.context] (default task-17) javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null identifier
```

Se eu utilizo o annotaion `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)`, obtenho o erro:

```
SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.context] (default task-17) javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: Unknown integral data type for ids : java.lang.String
```

O ID está denifido na entidade como:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) //??
@Column(name = "id", length = 36, updatable = false, nullable = false)
private String id;
```

Comment: Dá uma olhada nessa resposta no SO em inglês, talvez te ajude: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3079671/4730201

Comment: qual versão do SQL Server ?

Comment: @LR10 versão 2008

Comment: Não deu certo ? com a sequence?

Comment: Funcinou, @RicardoPontual. Muito obrigado!

Answer (score -1):

**Adicionar essa propriedade ao meu arquivo:**

```
<property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value="false" />
```

Ajuda - https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11014

ou você pode criar uma sequence na sua tabela.

```
@SequenceGenerator(name="sua_table_id_seq", sequenceName =  "sua_table_id_seq")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "sua_table_id_seq")
@Id
@Column(name = "id", length = 36, updatable = false, nullable = false)
private String id;
```

Comment: Só funciona se eu remover `strategy = GenerationType.AUTO`

Comment: remova então. A sua sequense já vai fazer a isso coloca IDENTITY!!

Comment: Se deu certo vota na resposta para outras pessoas também usar.